# Android Studio 4.1 - Error Loading Studio (JAVA_HOME & JVM)

Tags: android-studio

**HISTORY**
Android Studio was installed successfully the first time during a walk through as part of a Flutter tutorial (including installing Git and Flutter)

Trying to launch Android Studio the second time produced the following error:

[Error launching Studio

If you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.

Failed to create JVM.  JVM Path: C:\Users\Anthony.AndroidStudio4.0\jre\jre][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ5x1.jpg)

**RESEARCH**
I've seen several YouTube videos addressing this that appear to be successful, but just don't work for me.

[Video showing how to delete VMoptions file and check JAVA_HOME:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq-NWGg-3hQ)
(my folders seem to be configured differently, but I have two VMoptions files in the bin and one in the AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1   The one in AppData just contained a link to an Android support page, but the one in bin had a lot of data.  It was deleted (first just the contained data within and later the file was deleted entirely)

**Key points:**
It seems that the issue is either with Android Studio or the Java JDK

**JAVA**

1. I've downloaded and installed Java JDK 13, and set the bin folder as the environment variable (both system variable and path) as shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJ-PJbvJBGs
2. I've also tried with JDK 8 (legacy version) with the same results

**ANDROID STUDIO**

1. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Studio 4.1 and the same thing happens.  I can't locate prior versions on their site.

**COMPUTER** Windows 10, i7, 32gb ram

Comment: Hello Anthony, may I ask if you can share : 

- the output of `java -version` when you run it in the command line ?
- what is the path for `JAVA_HOME` ? if you can share an image, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

value = "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre"

- Android studio 4.1, Flutter